# How to add action in text hover?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hover

[image: javadoc assistance in eclipse]

You can see at the upper left corner of java doc has one link or action. On clicking that link control directly redirected to declaration of the variable or method or class. As you can see in above image mouse pointer is on **`hoverRegion`**, after clicking on that upper left corner link control directly redirected to its declaration which is the parameter of method **`getHoverInfo`** . I want to implement similar functionality except clicking on that link should appear a dialog box.

In short i want to add that link in my text hover. How can i implement that?